# Testng: Skip/Failed Rest of Tests If There is An Exception

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am writing my tests using Selenium and TestNG on Java. How can I skip/fail the rest of a Test when an exception is caught?

For example like if I have 3 steps on a test

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public void login() {

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void checkLoginResult() {

    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void submitImage() {

    }
```

How can I skip the rest of the test for example if there is a Selenium exception caught (TimeOutException i.e) on the first test 'login'?

Is there some annotation or any method that can be used for this purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Check `dependsOnMethods` in the TestNG documentation:

> http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations

If you add this parameter to the second and third test, they won't get executed if the first test failed:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void login() {

}

@Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods = {"login"})
public void checkLoginResult() {

}

@Test(priority = 3, dependsOnMethods = {"login"})
public void submitImage() {

}
```

Comment: `priority` is useless now, you could remove them

Comment: Not really useless, because you can give the order with priority to those methods, which depends on another methods. So in this case the `checkLoginResult()` method will run always  before the `submitImage()` method.

Comment: What you describe is just `submitImage` which depends on `checkLoginResult`.No need to make it complex by mixing priority and dependsOnMethods.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test(priority = 2,dependsOnMethods={"login"})
    public void checkLoginResult() {

    }

    @Test(priority = 3,dependsOnMethods={"login","checkLoginResult"})
    public void submitImage() {

    }
```

This way the dependents will be skipped. To fail them write a listener class where you can check after every method failure, if the method that failed has depndant methods and then you can fail them. Something like this can be done.